# Loading hooks in CucumberJS with Protractor and Gulp

Tags: javascript, cucumber, bdd, cucumberjs

I setup CucumberJS with Protractor and Gulp. I followed the documentation available here: 
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js

I have my feature file and step definition file. I also created world.js file in support folder and it is loaded in my step definition file with:

```
this.World = require("../support/world.js").World;
```

So the same way as it is presented in the documentation.
Everything works till this moment.

I tried to add some cucumber hooks to my case. I created hooks.js file in the support folder as it is proposed in the documentation, so:

```
// features/support/hooks.js (this path is just a suggestion)

var myHooks = function () {
 this.Before(function (callback) {
    // Just like inside step definitions, "this" is set to a World instance.
    // It's actually the same instance the current scenario step definitions
    // will receive.

    // Let's say we have a bunch of "maintenance" methods available on our World
    // instance, we can fire some to prepare the application for the next
    // scenario:

    console.log("Before hook");

    // Don't forget to tell Cucumber when you're done:
    callback();
  });
};

module.exports = myHooks;
```

The documentation does not say how this hook.js file should be loaded in my step definitions so I assume that it is somehow loaded with the "convention over configuration" approach. Unfortunately, the file is not loaded and the Before method is not executed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If hooks are NOT in the same folder as your step_definitions, you would need to explicitly specify where your hooks are using `--require`. For example,

```
 cucumber.js test/functional/features/xyz.feature 
--require test/functional/step_definitions/ 
--require features/support/ --format=pretty
```

To avoid this, I usually keep my hooks under step_definitions folder. Since you need to specify require for step_definitions anyways, you don't need to explicitly specify require for hooks. So lets say if your hooks are in `test/functional/step_definitions/`, with following your hooks should get invoked.

```
 cucumber.js test/functional/features/xyz.feature 
--require test/functional/step_definitions/ 
--format=pretty
```

Comment: Thanks! It might work, but I have different folder structures. For example to test user management features I have: /test/e2/features/user/xyz.feature and  /test/e2/features/user/step-definitions/step-defs.js. In this approach I would need to put hook.js in the step-defs of every feature which doesn't really make sense. I could try to use the --require option, however, I'm not sure how it would work with gulp.

Comment: Why not have a top level folder like /test/e2/features/step-definitions and have users folder underneath it and put hooks.js at step-definitions level. Or in your current setup you could try putting hooks.js under feature folder. That should work too. Let us know what works and what doesn't

Comment: First approach doesn't really work as I would like to keep features files and step definitions together in the same folder, so having together  /test/e2/features/user/xyz.feature  and  /test/e2/features/user/step-definitions/step-defs.js. Your ideas makes me put my feature file under  /test/e2/features/step-definitions/user folder, if I understood you correctly.

I also tried putting hooks.js under fetures folder, but it did not help.

Comment: Since step definitions are global to all tests, it doesn't really make sense to "group them" under feature folders. The Cucumber Book, published by Pragmatic Press is a great book for understanding how to use cucumber (even if its examples are in Ruby--but cucumber was originally written for the Ruby community). Anyway, the recommended folder structure is a `features` folder that contains all your `*.feature` files, and which contains a `step_definitions` folder containing all step definitions, and a `support` folder in the `features` folder containing the `World` and any hooks.

Comment: Also, note that by placing your `step_definitions` and `support` code under the `features` folder, you won't need to use the `--require` flag, as cucumber will automatically look for step definitions and support code recursively in folders below where the `*.feature` files are located.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your `hooks.js` file, go to your `cucumberOpts` inside of your ***protractor.conf.js*** file and add the path to your hooks.js file there, that's it, your hooks.js file will be loaded.

```
cucumberOpts: {
    require: [
      conf.paths.e2e + '/steps/**/*Steps.js',
      conf.paths.e2e + '/utilities/hooks.js',
    ],
    tags: ['~@wip', '~@manual'],
    format: 'pretty'
  }
```

You can also include ***console.log('Was my hook loaded')*** in your ***hooks.js*** file and search for that log text later to ensure your hook was properly loaded.